# Цветной вывод в консоль с помощью функции WriteConsoleOutputCharacter (C#)

Tags: c#, winapi, консоль, color, ansi

Разрабатываю консольную ASCII-игру на C#. Мне нужно максимально быстро выводить матрицу символов на экран. Узнал про функцию WriteConsoleOutputCharacter из WinAPI, и она действительно оказалась самым оптимизированным вариантом. Вот только мне непонятно, как настроить для каждого символа его собственный цвет и цвет его фона. Я реализовал этот момент с помощью 24-битной версии ANSI-color: `"\x1b[48;2;" + 100 + ";" + 0 + ";" + 0 + "m\x1b[38;2;" + 0 + ";" + 200 + ";" + 0 + "m" + "~"`. Console.Write правильно это выводит, а WriteConsoleOutputCharacter не понимает управляющие последовательности ANSI. Как можно изменить цвет каждого символа матрицы/его фона по отдельности, не теряя сильно в производительности?

P.S. Меня устроит решение и с меньшим количеством цветов, главное избавиться от одноцветности.

Ключевые для задачи фрагменты кода:

```
public static class Output
{
    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleMode( IntPtr hConsoleHandle, int mode );
    
    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
    public static extern bool GetConsoleMode( IntPtr handle, out int mode );

    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle( int handle );
    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, string lpCharacter, uint nLength, Point16 dwWriteCoord, out uint lpNumberOfCharsWritten);

    private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
    private const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
    private const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;
    private static readonly IntPtr _stdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Point16
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;

        public Point16(short x, short y)
            => (X, Y) = (x, y);
    }
    
    public static string[,] matrix;
    public static StringBuilder sb;
    
    public static void Init()
    {
        int mode;
        GetConsoleMode( _stdOut, out mode );
        SetConsoleMode( _stdOut, mode | 0x4 );
        matrix = new string[Console.WindowHeight, Console.WindowWidth];
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    
    public static void WriteToBufferAt(string text, int x, int y)
    {
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(_stdOut, text, (uint)text.Length, new Point16((short)x, (short)y), out uint _);
    }
    
    public static void Map()
    {
        // *инициализация всех элементов матрицы*
        foreach (string s in matrix)
        {
            sb.Append(s);
        }
        WriteToBufferAt(sb.ToString(), 0, 0);
        sb.Clear();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    }
}

public static class Game
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Output.Init();
        Output.Map();
    }
}
```

[image: С использованием WriteConsoleOutputCharacter]

[image: С использованием Console.Write]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет [WriteConsoleOutputAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute). Работает точно так же как `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` только вместо символа - цвет (`short[]` вместо `string`). То есть за 2 системных вызова можно отрисовать всю консоль целиком. Посимвольно выводить не требуется.

Никакие терминальные символы при записи напрямую в буфер консоли не поддерживаются. Буфер консоли - это просто память, там нет никаких препроцессоров при выводе, поэтому оно и работает быстро.

Comment: Сколько цветов будет доступно с помощью этой функции? 16 стандартных?

Comment: @Kostyable верно, по ссылке на документацию это всё указано. _For more information, see [Character Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes)._

Comment: @Kostyable удалось разобраться?

Comment: да, только вывод стал заметно медленнее, чем с Console.Write(). Я думаю, это связано с тем, что добавляется ещё массив short[], и процессору нужно больше времени на обработку (в Full HD, например, в консоли 240x63=15120 символов).

Comment: @Kostyable видимо потому что посимвольно выводите. Но это проблема того что ваш код медленный, а не системный вызов. Надо переписывать чтобы быстро было. Задайте отдельный вопрос, чтобы можно было код запустить, проверить и измерить производительность.